# The simpliest way to dequeue atomically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a set of data that must be processed simultaneously by using multi-threading, the number of data supposedly is bigger than the number of threads. I decided to put the data into some kind of a queue so each free thread can pop its part and process it until the queue is empty. I could use a simple STL queue and lock it by a mutex when I want to dequeue an element out of it, but I'd like to try a lock-free approach. At the same time my project is too small to depend on some 3rd-party library that provides lock-free structures, in fact I need only atomic dequeuing. So I decided to implement my own queue based on a vector with a pointer to the "head" and increment this pointer atomically:

```
template <typename T>
class AtomicDequeueable
{
public:

    // Assumption: data vector never changes
    AtomicDequeueable(const std::vector<T>& data) :
        m_data(data),
        m_pointer(ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0))
    {}

    const T * const atomicDequeue()
    {
        if (std::atomic_load(&m_pointer) < m_data.size())
        {
            return &m_data
            [
                std::atomic_fetch_add(&m_pointer, std::size_t(1))
            ];
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:

    AtomicDequeueable(const AtomicDequeueable<T>&) {}

    std::atomic_size_t m_pointer;
    const std::vector<T>& m_data;
};
```

Threads' function looks as follows:

```
void f(AtomicDequeueable<Data>& queue)
{
    while (auto dataPtr = queue.atomicDequeue())
    {
        const Data& data = *dataPtr;
        // processing data...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

My experience using lock-free structures and primitives is really poor, so I wonder: will my approach work properly? Surely I have tested it on Ideone, but I don't know how it will behave with real data.

Comment: Lock-free and simple? Oh boy. You have a data race in your code. Imagine that your queue of size `n` is filled to `n - 1`, now two threads simultaneously succeed in `std::atomic_load(&m_pointer) < m_data.size()`: you'll have UB once they do the atomic increment because one thread will access `m_data[ n - 1 ]` and another will access `m_data[ n ]`.

Comment: Your `atomicDequeue` function doesn't look atomic. Think about what happens if 2 threads get through the if statement when `m_pointer` is `m_data.size()-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `atomicDequeue` function has a data race: it is possible for 2 threads to have both executed the first `atomic` instruction before executing the second. However, this can be fixed as you really only need 1 atomic operation, as per the following change:

```
const T * const atomicDequeue()
{
    auto myIndex = std::atomic_fetch_add(&m_pointer, std::size_t(1));

    if(myIndex >= m_data.size())
        return nullptr;

    return &m_data[myIndex];
}
```

This works provided nothing modifies the input vector during thread operation.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very buggy. Let me be very frank in my recommendation here:

- *"**Actum Ne Agas:**   Do not do a thing already done."*   You have *plenty* of pre-existing C++ classes available to you which can reliably do queueing, and interprocess communication (IPC) in-general.  Use one of them.
- Don't worry about "lock free." That's what locks are *for,* and they're reliable, fast, and cheap.

Your notion of "using a queue" is sound, but you are going to unnecessary work ... and creating bugs ... when you can simply "grab something off the shelf." You know that the standard part will work correctly because other people have tested it to death.